# AngularJS : How do I execute an array of defered in order?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, deferred

I have an array of async functions, where it only makes sense to run one if the previous one has been resolved. You can think of them as HTT get requests to different URL, e.g.

```
$http.get('/step1')
$http.get('/step2')
$http.get('/step3')
$http.get('/step4')
```

How can I serialize them?

EDIT: There are N of them in an array. So I can't explicitly unroll them and join them with 'then', e.g.:

```
var calls = Array()

for(var i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    var d = $q.defer();

    ...

    calls.push(d.promise);
}

..

// How to do resolve the elements of 'calls' in order?
```

EDIT 2:

I would like:

```
Running Step #0 
Step completed: #0 OK 
Running Step #1 
Step completed: #1 OK 
Running Step #2 
Step completed: #2 OK 
Running Step #3 
Step completed: #3 OK 
Running Step #4 
Step completed: #4 OK 
Running Step #5 
Step completed: #5 OK
```

Not

```
Running Step #0 
Running Step #1 
Running Step #2 
Running Step #3 
Running Step #4 
Running Step #5 
Step completed: #0 OK 
Step completed: #1 OK 
Step completed: #2 OK 
Step completed: #3 OK 
Step completed: #4 OK 
Step completed: #5 OK
```

Comment: Call them synchronously, or make the response handler for the previous make the request for the next one (chaining the requests)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using lodash for brevity.

```
_.reduce(_.rest(calls), function(promise, call) {
  return promise.then(function() {
    return call();
  });
}, _.first(calls)()).then(function() {
  // do something after they are all done sequentially.
});
```

Comment: After looking at it, had to fix a small typo.
It calls the first promise and passes it into the reduce function. The reduce function iterates over all the remaining calls, passing each one into the function along with the return value of the previous iteration (the promise to resolve before making the next call). We then wait for the promise to resolve and make the call, returning the promise after making the call so that the next iteration will wait until it is complete before making the next call.

Answer (score 2):

```
var cur = $q.when();
var promises = [$http.get('/step1'), $http.get('/step2'), ...];

promises.forEach(function(promise){
    cur = cur.then(function(){
        return promise;
    });
})

cur.then(function(){
    //All done
})
```

Comment: The deferreds are in an array. And there are N of them, so I can't explicitly unroll it

Comment: @nickponline err wait a second, this still executes them all in parallel

Comment: @Esailija: This probably needs jQuery 1.8 or later, as with earlier versions, I think `then` returns the original promise, not a new one sequencing the two. While OP didn't mention the jQuery version, it's kinda important here. @nickponline: So why can't you loop through them? Just grab the new promise returned by `then` and use that for the next iteration of the loop. Post edit: so, do you need to call them in a specific order, or do they just need to resolve in a specific order?

Comment: @JayC op is using angular not jQuery, angular has real promises

Comment: Yeah still executing in parallel. @JayC I need to call the next one when the previous one is resolved. Each changes the state on a server and it only makes sense to call one if the previous has completed.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to do this without jQuery

Comment: Output is: Running Step #0 
Running Step #1 
Running Step #2 
Running Step #3 
Running Step #4 
Running Step #5 
Step completed: #0 OK 
Step completed: #1 OK 
Step completed: #2 OK 
Step completed: #3 OK 
Step completed: #4 OK 
Step completed: #5 OK 
Where as I would like:Running Step #0 
Step completed: #0 OK 
Running Step #1 
Step completed: #1 OK 
Running Step #2 
Step completed: #2 OK 
Running Step #3 
Step completed: #3 OK 
Running Step #4 
Step completed: #4 OK 
Running Step #5 
Step completed: #5 OK

Comment: My mistake, it is correct, the promises just needed to be constructed in the then() method otherwise they begin executing immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Your array needs to be of the data you want to use, and the function call done after the previous promise has resolved. You could adapt @Esailija's solution by putting the call inside the `cur.then` function, however the idiomatic way to do this is with `[].reduce`:

```
var urls = ["/step1", "/step2", "step3"];

var done = urls.reduce(function (previous, url) {
    return previous.then(function () {
        return $http.get(url);
    });
}, $q.when());

done.then( ... );
```

See Kris Kowal's [Qooqbooq](https://github.com/kriskowal/qooqbooq/blob/master/tutorial.md#sequences)

Comment: As of Angular.js 1.2, `$q.when()` doesn't seem to trigger itself anymore. I had to substitute `$q.when()` with `myDeferred.promise` then call `myDeferred.resolve()`.